# NSArrayController bind to ViewController array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm wondering if it's possible to bind a ViewController's array property to an NSArrayController.

In my main.xib I have one ViewController object and one NSArrayController. So I'd like to bind the ViewController's array property to the NSArrayController's content.

It seems only to work if the NSArrayController is bound to File's Owner. If I move the code to the ViewController and repeat the steps to setup the content - it doesn't work.

The code to setup a fixed size array shown here

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSArray *sandboxArray;

self.sandboxArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];
```

Comment: You can bind NSArrayController's content array property to ViewController's sandboxArray. ViewController owns sandboxArray so it should be a strong reference. Is the code to initialise sandboxArray executed?

Comment: @Willeke yes it's executed. I thought all delegates and IBOutlet properties should be set to weak? Is it necessary to declare it as IBOutlet for it to be displayed in the Bind To dropdown?

Comment: IBOutlet isn't necessary.